# Why am I getting a -1 for the network prefix length in Java?

Tags: java, networking, interface, prefix, addressing

So I'm writing a program that creates a list of all of the IP addresses from the Network address to the Broadcast address and then looping through them and checking if they are available. The code I have works perfectly fine on wired networks, but as soon as I try it on a WiFi network things get wonky. I'll receive a -1 for the prefix length and this causes my code to loop through 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 which is just... terrible.

The following code is how I'm getting the NetworkInterfaces. The problem could be that I'm checking the wrong interface or am not checking it correctly.

```
InetAddress host_address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
NetworkInterface net_int = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(host_address);
int host_subnet = net_int.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0).getNetworkPrefixLength();
out.println(host_address);
```

From what I understand this should work, but it doesn't. I get the correct prefix on wired connections, but -1 on wireless networks. I feel like this is a rookie mistake but I'm a rookie so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Any help would be appreciated, thanks you.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(net_int.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0))` output?

Comment: How can you be sure that the first interface is the correct one?